# Нужна помощь с позиционированием 2 кнопок

Tags: html, css3

[image: Вот как должно получится]

```
<div class="sliderArrows">
                <a class="slideLeft" href="#"><img src="img/png/left.png" alt="left"></a>
                <a class="slideRight" href="#"><img src="img/png/right.png" alt="right"></a>
            </div>
```

css
    .

```
    .sliderArrows{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
    }
    .slideRight{
        right: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи `flex`

```css
.sliderArrows {
  /* ↓↓↓ */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  /* ↑↑↑ */
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderArrows">
  <a class="slideLeft" href="#"><img src="img/png/left.png" alt="left"></a>
  <a class="slideRight" href="#"><img src="img/png/right.png" alt="right"></a>
</div>
```

---

При помощи `position: absolute` и `transform: translateY`

```css
.sliderArrows {
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  /* ↓↓↓ */
  position: relative;
  /* ↑↑↑ */
}

.sliderArrows .slideLeft,
.sliderArrows .slideRight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sliderArrows .slideLeft {
  left: 0;
}

.sliderArrows .slideRight {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderArrows">
  <a class="slideLeft" href="#"><img src="img/png/left.png" alt="left"></a>
  <a class="slideRight" href="#"><img src="img/png/right.png" alt="right"></a>
</div>
```